install awscli on java 17 docker
I am upgrading JAVA8 to JAVA17(FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk) with one of my Spring boot service. I have awscli being installed as with below command in my Dockerfile
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    python3 \
    py3-pip \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip \
&& pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
    awscli \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

But after upgrading to Java17 I am getting below issue and I can not continue with above step
    => ERROR [plp-svc 2/7] RUN apk add --no-cache         python3         py3-pip     && pip3 install --upgrade pip     && pip3 install --no-cache-dir         awscli     && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*              5.0s
------
 > [plp-svc 2/7] RUN apk add --no-cache         python3         py3-pip     && pip3 install --upgrade pip     && pip3 install --no-cache-dir         awscli     && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*:
0.165 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.546 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
0.894 fetch https://apk.corretto.aws/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
1.010 (1/25) Installing libexpat (2.6.2-r0)
1.033 (2/25) Installing libbz2 (1.0.8-r6)
1.054 (3/25) Installing libffi (3.4.4-r3)
1.383 (4/25) Installing gdbm (1.23-r1)
1.432 (5/25) Installing xz-libs (5.4.5-r0)
1.499 (6/25) Installing libgcc (13.2.1_git20231014-r0)
1.535 (7/25) Installing libstdc++ (13.2.1_git20231014-r0)
1.637 (8/25) Installing mpdecimal (2.5.1-r2)
1.668 (9/25) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.4_p20231125-r0)
1.717 (10/25) Installing libncursesw (6.4_p20231125-r0)
1.763 (11/25) Installing libpanelw (6.4_p20231125-r0)
1.797 (12/25) Installing readline (8.2.1-r2)
1.879 (13/25) Installing sqlite-libs (3.44.2-r0)
2.007 (14/25) Installing python3 (3.11.9-r0)
3.018 (15/25) Installing python3-pycache-pyc0 (3.11.9-r0)
3.464 (16/25) Installing pyc (3.11.9-r0)
3.482 (17/25) Installing py3-setuptools-pyc (68.2.2-r0)
3.623 (18/25) Installing py3-pip-pyc (23.3.1-r0)
3.884 (19/25) Installing py3-parsing (3.1.1-r0)
3.913 (20/25) Installing py3-parsing-pyc (3.1.1-r0)
3.948 (21/25) Installing py3-packaging-pyc (23.2-r0)
3.974 (22/25) Installing python3-pyc (3.11.9-r0)
3.993 (23/25) Installing py3-packaging (23.2-r0)
4.020 (24/25) Installing py3-setuptools (68.2.2-r0)
4.103 (25/25) Installing py3-pip (23.3.1-r0)
4.320 Executing busybox-1.36.1-r15.trigger
4.324 OK: 398 MiB in 42 packages
4.778 error: externally-managed-environment
4.778 
4.778 × This environment is externally managed
4.778 ╰─> 
4.778     The system-wide python installation should be maintained using the system
4.778     package manager (apk) only.
4.778     
4.778     If the package in question is not packaged already (and hence installable via
4.778     "apk add py3-somepackage"), please consider installing it inside a virtual
4.778     environment, e.g.:
4.778     
4.778     python3 -m venv /path/to/venv
4.778     . /path/to/venv/bin/activate
4.778     pip install mypackage
4.778     
4.778     To exit the virtual environment, run:
4.778     
4.778     deactivate
4.778     
4.778     The virtual environment is not deleted, and can be re-entered by re-sourcing
4.778     the activate file.
4.778     
4.778     To automatically manage virtual environments, consider using pipx (from the
4.778     pipx package).
4.778 
4.778 note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
4.778 hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache         python3         py3-pip     && pip3 install --upgrade pip     && pip3 install --no-cache-dir         awscli     && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Is there any way I can run my old command without using virtual environment.
I did changed my command to use virtual environment to install awscli with below command and got worked.
#Install python3 and pip
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip

# Create and activate a virtual environment, then install awscli
RUN python3 -m venv /venv \
    && . /venv/bin/activate \
    && pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache awscli \
    && deactivate

But my app is failing with below error to get the aws credentials as it was not installed instead in a virtual environment
Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: To use assume role profiles the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path., com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@4afd1baf: profile file cannot be null, com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@7a2c4bf0: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

What are you hoping to do with the AWS CLI tool?  Could you do it in Java code instead?  Is there a prepackaged Alpine version you could install with apk?

(Note that the error you're getting at the end is a Java error, and more specifically the aws-java-sdk-sts module must be on the class path.  That's something to fix in your build.gradle or pom.xml file.  The Python-based CLI tool won't produce this error and can't solve it.)

Ok, How about the Error that i am getting when running the Docker script to install awscli OR pip3
